# Google toolbar in C# web browser?

Tags: c#, browser, google-toolbar

I am working on web Browser in C# and I want to ask if is possible to integrate google toolbar somehow? I am looking for some easy solution to block pop up windows and google toolbar includes this protection.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Thanks for answers.
choze88, Czech Republic.

Comment: Which rendering engine do you use? Or are you writing your own?

Comment: I'm guessing he means the existing WebBrowser *control*.

Comment: I am using the existing WebBrowser control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible if you write a host for [Browser Helper Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object), the interface used for the Google Toolbar.